# How to add cookiebot Cookie Declaration in Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2.4, footer, script

How to add cookiebot Cookie Declaration in Magento 2.4.0

```
<script id="CookieDeclaration" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/cd.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Comment: add src_type="url" attribute in script tag.

Comment: just src to repace src_type @Rohan Hapani

Comment: No it's new attribute src_type need to add.

Comment: Not working @Rohan Hapani

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Create the **cookiebot.js** at below path,

path : **app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/web/js**

```
require([
    'https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js?cbid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'domReady!'
], function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log(Cookiebot);
});
```

**2.** set the js file path in **default_head_blocks.xml** file with below path,

path : **app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Theme::js/cookiebot.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**3.** **after run the below commnds,**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
<script id="CookieDeclaration" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/cd.js" src_type="url" />
```